# Do materialists today consider physical forces as created from matter?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, materialism, physicalism

The distinction from materialism and physicalism is usually that materialists believe everything is matter, and physicalists believe that everything is physical, which lets them include modern science discoveries under their belief.

Now, it seem obvious that a "regular" sense of materialism today is absurd, if one is to believe in the scientific discoveries. So, my question would be, do materialists today still consider physical forces as somehow purely matter, or is materialism in its traditional sense nonexistent today, completely replaced with physicalism?

Comment: Modern physics tell us that all forces are mediated by exchange **particles** (photons, W/Z-bosons, gluons), except for gravitons where the only why to exhibit the particle character of'em by using the whole universe a measurement apparatus. Okay you might argue with the [wave-particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality)...maybe we should call them wave-matter-dualists nowadays...

Comment: I don't think materialists have ever considered that "everything" is made of matter. Space, time, and vacuum aren't matter for most materialists - even those of ancient times.

Comment: +1  E=mc^2 provides a way to link matter (m) with energy (E). One could view this as a monism regardless of the answers you may get. I don't accept either materialism or physicalism, so I will not try to answer your question.

Comment: @LuísHenrique what is the difference then between them and physicalists?

Comment: @FrankHubeny I'm not sure this is correct, as materialists (as far as I understand it) won't be able to even use E as something "real". But this is a good direction I think. Maybe it can be an answer, replacing everything that's considered energy with matter.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - I think there is a preceding question: is there any difference between materialists and "physicalists"? If so, it is clearly not what you describe in the OP, since "materialists" in such way do not exist. Not even Democritus - who thought gods were made of atoms - ever thought time or space are made of atoms.

Comment: What is the "regular" sense of materialism? Physicalism is typically seen  as a *narrower* position, as in reducing everything to matter that obeys causal laws of the kind we encounter in modern physics. [Non-reductive materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism#Overview), on the other hand, has a more liberal interpretation, where "properties" of matter have ontological basis not reducible to causal laws, laws of nature do not all reduce to laws of physics (say in biology), there are complementary descriptive languages not translatable into each other (mental/physical), etc.

Comment: @Conifold the simple presentation of both in Wikipedia (materialism) and SEP (physicalism): materialism - "Materialism is a form of philosophical monism which holds that matter is the fundamental substance in nature, and that all things, including mental aspects and consciousness, are results of material interactions". Physicalism - "Physicalism is the thesis that everything is physical, or as contemporary philosophers sometimes put it, that everything supervenes on the physical". Or you want to state that this oversimplification is just wrong, which I'll accept if you do.

Comment: @LuísHenrique see comment above.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - If I correctly understand, you are contrasting a Wikipedia article about materialism with a SEP article on "physicalism"? I don't think this is a good idea; it would be better to contrast the respective articles in each site.

Comment: @LuísHenrique OK then, correct. Here is the Wikipedia quote on physicalism - "In philosophy, physicalism is the ontological thesis that " everything is physical", that there is "nothing over and above" the physical, or that everything supervenes on the physical."

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Isn't this what I just wrote, only stated more hazily ?  "Results of material interactions" may come from "propensities" or emergent phenomena, not necessarily from physical laws, and "fundamental substance" may have any number of properties. Indeed, the boundary between materialism and [property dualism a la Chalmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_dualism#Panpsychist_property_dualism) is extremely blurred.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss The SEP article on physicalism, for instance, seems to consider the words as synonims: *In this entry, I will adopt the policy of using both terms interchangeably, though I will typically refer to the thesis we will discuss as ‘physicalism’. It is important to note, though, that physicalism (i.e. materialism) is associated with a number of other metaphysical and methodological doctrines.*

Comment: @Conifold the key point in the distinction made in the quotes I brought is the difference between saying "matter is the fundamental substance" and "everything is physical" - physical being (according to Wikipedia): "A "physical property", in this context, may be a metaphysical or logical combination of properties which are physical in the ordinary sense... physicalists usually suppose the existence of various abstract concepts which are non-physical in the ordinary sense of the word; so physicalism cannot be defined in a way that denies the existence of these abstractions."

Comment: I think you are taking mottos too literally.  Of course, physicalists do not need "physical forces made from matter", they are fine with properties and relations attached to matter as long as those fall under causal laws. Materialists are not bound even by the latter.

Comment: @Conifold I looked through my questions because I remembered you said the thing that lead me to this thinking (I didn't even know the term physicalism before), but when I found it I was a bit disappointed to see it wasn't from you but rather from Quentin Ruyant (considering tagging him to enter the discussion) - "Just a terminological point: is common in the philosophy literature to talk about physicalism rather than materialism (mainly because contemporary physics does not necessarily take matter, rather than, say, energy to be the fundamental "stuff" so the term is more neutral)".

Comment: Maybe I simply completely misunderstood and thought he meant that physicalism is a different thing, while he actually meant what you said at first, that it's simply the same.

Comment: So maybe I should rephrase to "ontological materialism"? Or we can simply close this question altogether.

Comment: I would just leave it, perhaps others might have a similar confusion. There is even an answer which you can accept. I think there is a lot of terminological haziness in the current usage, and one has to look closely what exactly is meant by "physicalism" and "materialism", especially how much reductionism and realism is admitted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such contrast is valid.

Materialism is an old word, and it never meant the idea that "everything is matter". Rather, it has always beend contrasted to "idealism", and the issue between them isn't if everything is matter or everything is idea, but whether ideas originate from matter, or matter originates from ideas. No materialist will tell you that the idea of God is made of atoms; all of them will agree that the idea of God does not pre-exist thinking entities, all of which are made of matter. Conversely, very few, if any, idealists would sustain that a copy of the Holy Bible isn't made of matter.

In such way, there is no meaningful contrast between "materialism" and "physicalism": the terms are synonims. But the latter word, according to the SEP, was coined by two minor philosophers, Neurath and Carnap, to mark the distinction between their position and materialism: materialism would be a "metaphysical", and as such nonsencical, position about reality; "physicalism" would be their idea (in their opinion, merely linguistic and not "metaphysical") that "every statement is synonymous with a physical statement" - which of course, boils down to linguistic idealism.

In this sense, there is a meaningful contrast between "materialism" and "physicalism", but the latter is merely a variant of linguistic idealism (language creates reality, not the other way round).